# Firebase Analytics + Android app (not in market)

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Help me please. 
I have android app(apk), which downloaded direct from site.
When user click advertising banner - (in this step i need send fingerprint to Firebase (step A)) -  he goes to the download page. (on mobile phone) 
I need information, from where the user came to the page. For marketing department. I need put this information to Firebase. After that user downloaded app, installed it and opened. After user launch the app info about user send to Firebase (step B). How I can match info from step A and step B?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the ad is served, Firrbase would capture parameters on the dashboard:

Served using [Google Play URL tool Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) (For AdMob banner) - The parameters appended on the campaign URL would be automatically captured in Firebase Console under attributions --> first_open --> source/medium/campaign.

Served using Firebase Dynamic Links - Analytics generated from these Links should be reported under automatically collected *dynamic_link_first_open, dynamic_link_app_open, dynamic_link_app_update* events provided implementation in [record analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#record-analytics) section is followed.

From client side, developers can log a [CAMPAIGN_DETAILS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#CAMPAIGN_DETAILS) event along with parameters to get the data in the app.